# Dynamically accessing nested movie clips in flash actionscript 2

Tags: flash, dynamic, variables, actionscript-2, movieclip

I have a nested movie clip instance that I want to access.  The path to the movie clip is defined by two variables ( similar to a row and column).

I am already dynamically accessing the parent movie clip like this:

eval("row" + ActiveRow)

Now I want to access one of row(#)'s children called let(#) dynamically.

Here are my best guesses at accomplishing the task (neither one works):

var i:number;

eval("row" + ActiveRow + ".let" + i)
or
eval("row" + ActiveRow).eval("let" + i)

Thanks a lot for your effort and possible solution..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could try

```
this["row" + ActiveRow]["let" + i]
```

What would be better though is if when you create the instances you put them in an array... so maybe

```
var rowClips : Array = [];

for (var i : int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     var row : MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("row" + i, i);

     rowClips.push(row);
}
```

you can then call it by

```
rowClips[i];
```

Obviously depending on the situation there could be different logic to adding your MovieClips to an Array but essentially it's a much nicer way to store references to your MovieClips.

Comment: I will use an array for the clips.

Answer (score 1):

Once you access the parent movie clip, simply index into the child.  ActionScript 2 does not require you to use the `eval` function for looking up dynamic properties.  Simply use the object and the `[]` (array) operators to index the desired variable.

If your "row" objects are in the root of the current movie clip, you could simply use `_root[ "row" + ActiveRow ][ "let" + i ]`.

However, since you already have the initial movieclip via `eval("row"+ActiveRow)`, you can use this object to get the next level down.  For example, `eval("row" + ActiveRow)[ "let" + i ]`.

Flash borrows heavily from JavaScript, and like JavaScript, every object is essentially a hash table.  Using the dot operator is equivalent to using the [] (array) operator with a fixed string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The hash table makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like you're using a tabular data structure, so one easy way would be to create a two-dimensional array and just store the movie clips in there. Then you can  do lookups by index.

Alternatively, you name each of your movie clips (using the name property), and use getChildByName.

I.E getChildByName("row"+i).getChildByName("column"+i).